# C++ Accessing data in child classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

My question  is pretty much in the code that follows. I am trying to create an array of pointers to abstract objects each with an ID and cost. Then I create objects like cars and microwaves and assign the pointers to point to them. Once they are created, how do I access the child data from the array? Is that possible. How do I even access the child objects at all if the classes are created in the heap and pointed to in the base class array?

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual void outputInfo() =0;

private:
    int id;
    int cost;
};

class Car: public Object
{
public:
    void outputInfo(){cout << "I am a car" << endl;}

private:
    int speed;
    int year;

};

class Toaster: public Object
{
public:
    void outputInfo(){cout << "I am a toaster" << endl;}

private:
    int slots;
    int power;
};


int main()
{
    // Imagine I have 10 objects and don't know what they will be
    Object* objects[10];

    // Let's make the first object
    objects[0] = new Car;

    // Is it possible to access both car's cost, define in the base class and car's speed, define in the child class?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `protected` access modifier.

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual void outputInfo() =0;

protected:
    int id;
    int cost;
};
```

and override `outputInfo()` in sub-classes of `Object` which print id,cost and other fields.

Call the overridden method -`outputInfo()` via,

```
Object *object=new Car;
object->outputInfo();
delete object;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic_cast to downcast to the subclass:

```
if (Car* car = dynamic_cast<Car*>(objects[0]))
{
    // do what you want with the Car object
}
else if (Toaster* toaster = dynamic_cast<Toaster*>(objects[0]))
{
    // do what you want with the Toaster object
}
```

dynamic_cast returns a pointer to the subclass object if the object's runtime type is actually that subclass, or a null pointer otherwise.